# reading line by line from text file and output to array bash

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell, while-loop

I'm trying to read lines from a .txt and copy each line from the text to its own folder that was previously created with ARRAY

```
cat stores/locations.txt |while read -r LINE;do 
echo "$LINE" > county/${ARRAY[${i}]}/localstores.txt
done
```

when I run this it creates only 1 file in the directory county with one line of contact information for the store but what i really want it to do is to put a file in each element of the ARRAY instead of the parent folder county.

each line of data includes the following:

```
<storeid> <storename> <amountofEmployees> <nameofManager>
```

I'm super stuck and really would appreciate the help!

Comment: if we had sample data, we wouldn't have to guess, but my guess is that you want to append multiple lines into the `county/${ARRAY[${i}]}/localstores.txt` files. For that, you should be able to use `>>` redirection. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply.  the data is lines of information something along of the line of <storenumber> <storeaddress> <number of employees> <manager in charge> ..... so each line should be going to its own folder

Comment: Thanks for the sample data, that helps some. Did you try `>>` for append redirection? Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do that would be as below, which creates a new file for each of the line and optionally also adds the line to an array.

```
 declare -A myArray()

 while IFS= read -r line # Read a line
 do
    touch  mytargetpath/"$line.txt" # Creates a new file for each of the line in the desired path
    myArray+=("$line") # Append line to the array
 done < stores/location.txt
```

And print array contents as:-

```
# Print the file (print each element of the array)

for e in "${myArray[@]}"
do
    echo "$e"
done
```